# Titanium Appcelerator - Facebook Mobile App Install Ads

Tags: android, ios, facebook, titanium, facebook-ads-api

We have our app built for Android and iOS using Titanium Appcelerator. Our client is asking to take advantage of Facebooks "Mobile App Install Ads". http://developers.facebook.com/docs/concepts/mobile-ads/

Does Titanium have access to make the updates required to make this work?

> For the FB iOS SDK 3.0 or greater, add the following to your
> UIApplicationDelegate applicationDidBecomeActive selector:
>
> ```
> [FBSettings publishInstall:YOUR_APP_ID];
> ```
>
> For the FB Android SDK 3.0,add the following to onResume() of each Activity in your app:
>
> ```
> com.facebook.Settings.publishInstallAsync(context, YOUR_APP_ID);
> ```

Answer (score 2):

For iOS and android recently both were upgraded to 3.0, but the release (3.1.0) is only in the nightly builds and will not be out till mid-April.

[Heres the JIRA ticket.](https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-10422)

Not sure if you want to use a nightly build, but once you build an app with that you can either edit the source of Titanium directly or you can  edit the actual source code generated by Titanium Studio, for iOS just open up the XCode project and edit the `TiApp.m` file, specifically the `applicationDidBecomeActive` method. For Android it should be very similar.